# Go Cross compiler fails

Tags: go, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

When followed this link to do cross compilation!

http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go

**Failing at : % go-crosscompile-build-all**

**Getting Below error :**

*# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
go tool dist: FAILED: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
./make.bash: eval: line 135: syntax error near unexpected token `('*

Comment: Soon (August 2015, Go 1.5), this will be *so much* easier: http://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#18

Comment: you can use [gox](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox) while Go 1.5 is not released, it fairly simple

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> When followed this link to do cross compilation!
>
> http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go

The article clearly states that it is obsolete.

> An introduction to cross compilation with Go
>
> Hello. Thanks for reading this article. Now that Go 1.1 has been
>   released an [updated
>   version](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/09/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go-1-1)
>   of this article is available.

Follow the instructions in the updated article.

Comment: even the updated version ended up in the same compilation error. will try out gox as an alternative.,